# Generating option tags from a lookup table using for xml feature of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-loop, html-select

I have a lookup table that contains these columns:

```
id, name, value, colx, coly
```

I would like to be able to generate the following HTML:

```html
<option value="value1" data-colx="x1" data-coly="y1">name1</option>
<option value="value2" data-colx="x2" data-coly="y2">name2</option>
<option value="value3" data-colx="x3" data-coly="y3">name3</option>
<option value="value4" data-colx="x4" data-coly="y4">name4</option>
```

I would rather not use XSL to reformat the generated XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard.... try this:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (id INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), VALUE VARCHAR(20), colx VARCHAR(5), coly VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1, 'name1', 'value1', 'x1', 'y1'),
(2, 'name2', 'value2', 'x2', 'y2'),
(3, 'name3', 'value3', 'x3', 'y3'),
(4, 'name4', 'value4', 'x4', 'y4')

SELECT 
    value AS '@value',
    colx AS '@data-colx',
    coly AS '@data-coly',
    name AS 'text()'
FROM @Test
FOR XML PATH('option')
```

This gives me the output you're looking for:

```
<option value="value1" data-colx="x1" data-coly="y1">name1</option>
<option value="value2" data-colx="x2" data-coly="y2">name2</option>
<option value="value3" data-colx="x3" data-coly="y3">name3</option>
<option value="value4" data-colx="x4" data-coly="y4">name4</option>
```